# Appending data in a CSV in selenium automation

Tags: java, selenium, csv, automation

I have a CSV file in Resources of my automation script and I need to amend one cell value to a parameter value I get by creating a folder in a site, I ran this code but then an error comes:

`"(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)".`

Can anyone let me know how to write my parameter value to CSV file cell, please.
TIA

Method:

```
 public static void writeCSV(String filePath, String separator) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
             Writer outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(outStreamWriter)) {
            buffWriter.append("https://mobile/sample_v4.zip");
            buffWriter.append(separator);
            buffWriter.append(createdTitle);
            buffWriter.append(separator);
            buffWriter.append("http://2-title-conversion/documentlibrary");
            buffWriter.append(separator);
            buffWriter.append("TRUE");
            buffWriter.append(separator);
            buffWriter.append("TRUE");
            buffWriter.flush();
        }


@Test segment,

loginPg.writeCSV("C:\\Users\\urathya\\Documents\\Automation\\03-11\\resources\\CS.csv",",");
```

Comment: Please make sure your other java process is not running which using the file or file is not open in notepad or any editor

Comment: Thank you, but still it gives the same error :(

Comment: try with closing your ourput steam fileStream.close()

Comment: I got it to working, thanks a lot again

Comment: good know. BTW what was the issue?

Comment: Issue was the one you said first, my file was open as I had created a method prev to check it and I had not closed it.

Comment: Could you please mark my solution as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the output stream, please close it, it will close file and you can use the same file to append the data.